# Why is the black small arrow on my AdvancedSkeleton plugin not pointing towards the center of the locator

Tags: maya, inverse-kinematics

In the ADV plugin, the black small arrow points to the center position of the locator, which serves as the pole vector constraint for the joint.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PA6c.png)
But in the projects I obtained from others, this small black arrow points to the edge of the locator, and even the position it points to may change.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqZg.png)

This had a significant impact on me, as when I wrote a script to switch fk to ik, I moved the center position of this locator to the corresponding plane (such as in the picture where PoleLeg_L was moved to the plane composed of Hip_L and Knee_L bones), but at this point, the posture under ik deviated from that under fk. It seems that the point pointed by the black small arrow should be moved to the corresponding plane to obtain unbiased results. I'm not sure why the black small arrow points differently from the one in ADV. I hope someone can provide help. Thank you very much~